# How can i make "jwt"?

Tags: node.js

I try add "jwt" for Login , Before adding "jwt" The program was running, but after adding "jwt" did not work,And this gives mistake in the terminal,How can I add "jwt" correctly for "Login"

userController.js

```
 const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
 const fs=require('fs')
let secret = fs.readFileSync('secret.key')
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
console.log('LogIn');
let { email, password } = req.body;
console.log(email)
console.log(password);
const user={
    email:req.body.email,
    password:req.body.password
}  
const result = await User.findUserByEmail(email, password);
if (result == 1) {
    // jwt
    jwt.sign({ user }, secret, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ message: "username and password not correct" })
        }
        res.json({ token })
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Process succeeded'
    });
  }
   else {
     res.status(401).json({
        error: 'User login error'
    });
   }
  }
  module.exports = {
  login: login}
```

secret.key:

```
   algorithm192352
```

userRouter.js:

```
   const router = require('express').Router();
   const userController = require('../Controllers/userController');
   router.post('/login',userController.login);
```

Comment: and this is a part of errors in terminal:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'secret.key'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\abd-hiba-test (1-4-2020)\Controllers\userController.js:7:17)

Comment: Can you try `let secret = fs.readFileSync('./secret.key')`

Comment: @SenaCarbtc thank you for your answer,but my problem not solved.
the mistaks in terminal :
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './secret.key'

Comment: Do you have a secret.key file in the same directory as userController.js? If not, can you try going one level higher with `../secret.key`

Comment: i have Folder with name "Controller" and inside this Folder i have "secret.key" and usercontroller.js"

Comment: Try `fs.readFileSync('./Controllers/secret.key', 'utf-8');`

Comment: Thank you so much,this is the solution, i put fs.readFileSync('./Controllers/secret.key'); and My problem was solved.